# Cannot assign value of type [String] to type String? with text label

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, uitableview

I have problem with assign [String] value to Label. (or - better - to UITableView). I get error 'Cannot assign value of type [String] to type String?'

I tried with as? Strig and as! String, but this also not working well. The code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
var auctionDates = [String]()

let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fmt.dateFormat = "(EEE)"
    fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pl_PL")

    var date = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

    while auctionDates.count < 7 {
       let weekDay = cal.component(.Weekday, fromDate: date)
       if weekDay != 0 {
            auctionDates.append(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
       }
       date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    }
    print(auctionDates)
    self.myLabel.text = auctionDates

}
}
```

Any help would be great ;)

Comment: I know I can handle that with self.myLabel.text = "\(auctionDates[0]), \(auctionDates[1]), \(auctionDates[2]), \(auctionDates[3]), \(auctionDates[4]), \(auctionDates[5]), \(auctionDates[6])" But this option is crappy.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you hardcoding a locale to format the dates? People outside of Poland may prefer to see dates in their own format. And also note that `NSDateFormatter` already has the `shortWeekdaySymbols` property to get an array of weekday names. No need for all of the code you've written.

Answer (score 3):

- `auctionDates` is an **array** (a list of strings)
- `text` expects a **single string** (not a list)

There are many solutions, one of them is to flatten the list

```
self.myLabel.text = auctionDates.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```